# Is there any way to remove code from a sourceforge git repository?

Tags: git, sourceforge

I accidentally included code in a sourceforce git repository that I should not have. How do I remove it or my entire repository?

Comment: See: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data (applies to removing sensitive data, but the solution is equally applicable, I think).

Answer (score 0):

I could delete a branch of my repo using `git push --delete`.

```
git push --delete origin old-branch
```